# $row['imageData'] code below is not displaying the images

Tags: html-table, base64, row, src

This line of code is supposed to display images read from a mysql db table row = imageData into a html page. I only see the 100x100 and a ? instead of the actual image.

```
                <td><img src="data:uploads/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['imageData']).'" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></td>
```

Comment: but this does display the images <?php
      echo '<img width="100" height="100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['imageData'] ).'"/>';
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

resolved it with changing the  tags

>';?>

thanks, everyone....

hope it helps another driven member

Comment: <td<?php echo $column == 'Image' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo '<img width="100" height="100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['imageData'] ).'"/>';?></td>